# Can I use different styles within one div

Tags: html, css

I'm using a script to do a `mouseover` effect with images and also highlighting text in a different color using the `getElementById` phrase. I understand that an ID can only be used once, and if it needs to be used more than once I should use class. But there is no `getElementByClass` function. I have 2 areas of type that I want to highlight, one is centered, the other is left justified. Is there a way to use the same `id` for both styles?

```
<div id="georgia">
  <style="text-align: center;">
      <strong>Headquarters:
      </strong>
    </style>more text here
</div>
```

This is the script I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// < ![CDATA[
  function on(el) {    
    if (document.getElementById(el)) {              
      document.getElementById(el).style.color="green";
    };
  };
  function off(el) {
    if (document.getElementById(el)) {        
      document.getElementById(el).style.color="";
    };
  };
// ]]></script>
```

So what you are saying is I can replace the getElementById with getElementByClassName then it will work?

This is the format I'm using, the first part of the text (Headquarters) is not showing up, but the second part (more text here) is fine.

Comment: "*...But there is no getElementByClass function*..." - it's getElement**s**ByClass**Name**. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, as you're using `<style>` as a tag, when I think you want it as the style of `<div>` - for example `<div id="georgia" style="text-align:center">`

Comment: This is madness, why not just css `:hover`?

Comment: I am hovering over an image to change that image and text related to that image, there are 3 images with related text blocks that would be changed. I'm not a developer, I work by copy, pasting and trying to learn from doing so please be patient.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `document.getElementsByClassName`, which returns a list of the objects with that `class` name:

```js
var all = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++){
  var obj = all[i];
  obj.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  }
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="bar">hi</div>
<div class="bar">bye</div>
<div id="bar">sup</div>
```